# Balancing starting dots and XP at character creation

Tags: character-creation, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, balance, vampire-the-requiem

In *Vampire: The Requiem*, the character has points to spend between attributes, skills, disciplines, etc. Purchasing a new level in a skill, attribute or other merit has a linear cost.

During game however, the xp cost of new level depends on the level of the skill you want to improve, meaning that you **always** should min-max at character creation if you want to optimise the xp-value of your character.

Is there a way to neutralise this effect and ensure xp-equivalence of each character at creation, without needing to calculate too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

**Fix:**

Eliminate Bonus points *or* Undo the growing cost increase on attributes, skills, disciplines, etc. *or* Add the growing cost to Bonus Point pricing.

**The Problem**

Baring that, any time where character creation resources have a different math then leveling resources, there will be an 'optimal solution path' in which a character built using that path toward their desired power set will have a mathematical advantage over one that didn't.

In Vampire, it means if we have a guy (Bob) who bought Skills A, B, C, D, & E to four at character creation and a guy (John) who bought A, B, C, & D to five at Chara-gen, and they're both using XP to get rating five in A, B, C, D, & E, then John will have an extra ~15 xp to play with for following the path.

Answer (score -2):

I suppose one must first as, Why must one min-max the character?  If your looking at points on a sheet, then I wonder if any Storyteller system will work.

IE: The points on the sheet, should reflect the person. It actually takes more work to go from the Master's to a PhD than it does to go from Bachelor's to Master's, or HSD to Bachelors..

In that I feel the xCurrent Level XP buy is reflexive of natural progression. Also, backed by the rule that you cannot buy from 0 to 4 in a skill with XP. You have to buy them all incrementally.

If I recall, as I don't have my books:

0 > 1 3pts

1+ 2xCurrent level

so ..

1 > 2 2

2 > 3 4

3 > 4 6

etc, 
etc..

Now, pregame, what is the character? a Jack of all trades then yes, they should have a lot more points spread out and not min-maxed, a specialist will min-max. The backstory calls for it.

One modification that has proved successful in doing what I think you want, is to not only require the roleplay of working to improve a skill, but to add for a few players a 1 XP skill roleplay at the end of a session.  The idea being that a player purposefully chooses and wants to increase a skill or such, goes out of their way to use or or in fact practice.. That should be rewarded.

Comment: Your costs are oWoD. NWoD has a flat 3x level cost for skills.